# How can I use Bootstrap Toggle to process backend change state?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap Toggle to process task on backend via ajax. When I set checkbox to **Off**, I am expecting my server to set the state to **Off** and return success or failure via ajax. In case of failure, the button should go back to **On** state so that the user knows the process was unsuccessful

[image]

Here is my ajax code

```
function toggle_systemtask_plan(state) {

        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            contentType : "application/json",
            url : "toggle-system-task?state=" + state,
            dataType : 'json',
            timeout : 100000,
            success : function(data) {
              // HOW DO I PROCESS THIS HERE USING WHAT SERVER RETURNS
            },
          });
  }
```

The problem is once I process the change it calls the .change() function again making the ajax call to server once more.

I have tried using other events like click() and mousedown() but that is not recording the event when I toggle button(checkbox).

Comment: If i am right, then its just a class which is making button on and off , just remove that class instead calling toggle button

Answer (score 0):

```
function toggle_systemtask_plan(state) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: "toggle-system-task?state=" + state,
    dataType: 'json',
    timeout: 100000,
    success: function(data) {
      // HOW DO I PROCESS THIS HERE USING WHAT SERVER RETURNS
      // Success function
      $('#toggleElement').bootstrapToggle('on');
    },
    error: function(data) {
      // Error function
      $('#toggleElement').bootstrapToggle('of');
    }
  });
}
```

Explanation: Simply based on response from server.you can switch on & off event.